# Blender Rendering causes image to change

Tags: rendering

[image: build space] This is my animation tab and 3d viewport. When I try to render the image this happens: [image: renderred image] Why do rocks move? What did i do wrong?

I tried to replace the camera and rearrange rocks, but the issue still persists

Comment: We'd need to see your Blend file to answer definitely, but are you sure you don't have two sets of rocks in your scene with one enabled in the viewport and one for the render?

Answer (score 0):

For the ones that need the final solution:
I had a layer that contained rocks that I did not use, but still left them on

Make sure you do so as well!